# Calculation of Score when earning a specific tag badge

Tags: discussion, badges, tag-badges, score

Take for example the [Linq bronze badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/358/linq?userid=728795), where the description is

> Earned at least 100 total score for at least 20 answers in the linq
>   tag

How is **total score calculated**? is it based on the sum of **upvotes** and **downvotes**, and not the actual points you received based on questions/answers tagged with these badges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on the total score of the user on that tag. Just answers are taken into account.

To track it, you can check your "tags" page on your profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1449181/christiandev?tab=tags

these numbers are updated every night.

Comment: The question was for the calculation, as in if there's a question for C#, and I answer and get an upvote. The score is 1 (for 1 upvote) and not 10 (for upvote points) ?

Comment: @christiandev: how about you check out the links you got in comments to your question?

Comment: @christiandev it is based on the score. And score means `upvotes - downvotes`. Reputation is different.

Comment: @Mat, I have looked at these and it's clear.

Comment: Does the score work for questions that have the tag exclusively or does it also work if there are other tags on the question ?

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer it is independent. If a question has 5 tags, your score in that question adds up in all tags.